# Oracle SQL: Exclude IDs from another table without subquery join

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to know if the following is possible without joining the same table twice:

```
Table A:
+----+------+
| ID | ColA |
+----+------+
|  1 | A1   |
|  2 | A2   |
|  3 | A3   |
|  4 | A4   |
+----+------+

Table B:
+----+------+
| ID | ColB |
+----+------+
|  1 | B1   |
|  2 | B2   |
|  3 | B3   |
|  4 | B4   |
|  5 | B5   |
|  6 | B6   |
+----+------+

Table C:
+----+
| ID | 
+----+
|  1 | 
|  2 | 
+----+

Desired result: (A LEFT JOIN B WITHOUT C)
+----+------+------+
| ID | ColA | ColB |
+----+------+------+
|  3 | A3   | B3   |
|  4 | A4   | B4   |
+----+------+------+
```

So basically I need to add Column B to Table A, hence left join, and exclude all IDs which occur in Table C.

Current solution:

```
SELECT a.id, a.ColA, b.ColB
  FROM tableA a
  LEFT JOIN tableB b ON a.id = b.id
  WHERE a.id NOT IN(
    SELECT a2.id FROM tableA a2
    LEFT JOIN tableC c on a2.id = c.id)
```

What's irritating me is, that the exclusion of table C requires an additional left join of table A with table C. Isn't there a more straight-forward approach, without having to join table A again as part of the subquery, if all I want to do is to exclude IDs which occur in table C from the resultset?.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you left joining to table B -- if the id has to be there you want an inner join

Comment: I only need column B for the IDs of table A, hence the left join

Comment: If column B does not exist do you want to return a result?

Answer (score 2):

Use a not exists:

```
SELECT a.id, a.ColA, b.ColB
FROM tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b ON a.id = b.id
where not exists(select 1 from tablec c where a.id = c.id)
```

The issue with using a `not in` with a select in Oracle is that:

a) it has to return the whole subquery dataset

b) if there are nulls, it breaks

[TOM link regarding these 2 issues](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=not-in-operator-with-null-data)

Comment: a) there is no compiler that implements it this way b) how exactly does it break because of nulls?

Comment: @Hogan see [TOM](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=not-in-operator-with-null-data)

Comment: I see.  So not in is broken in oracle --- that is not an SQL standard.

Comment: @Hogan OP tagged Oracle, so I went with what is best in Oracle. ie, there **is** a compiler that implements it this way.

Comment: so if there is an index on c.id Oracle won't use it?

Comment: @Hogan I didn't say full tablescan, I said it returns the whole subquery dataset. A `not exists` stops the moment a row is returned

Comment: it is a correlated sub-query (a join) it needs to correlate on all source rows -- it can't stop after 1.

Answer (score 1):

won't this work?

```
SELECT a.id, a.ColA, b.ColB
FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.id NOT IN (SELECT c.Id FROM tableC c)
```

this can also be done in a join

```
SELECT a.id, a.ColA, b.ColB
FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b ON a.id = b.id
LEFT JOIN tableC C ON a.id = c.id 
WHERE c.Id is null
```